# How do I convert this list into a couple of strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code that adds the sum of rows in a matrix:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[1,0,0]]
answer = str([sum(row) for row in matrix])
print answer
```

But `answer` is a string that looks like `[3, 5, 1]`.

How can I convert `answer` to be `x` variables using a loop **(without .join)**?

Example if `answer = [3, 5, 1]` It should be :

`answer1 = "3"`

`answer2 = "5"`

`answer3 = "1"`

Comment: Answer is not a `string` it is a python array. It is becomes a string when you print it, because `print` can only print strings. Just loop over the array and you're done!

Comment: Why don't you just use the list?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[1,0,0]]
answer1,answer2,answer3 = [str(sum(row)) for row in matrix]
print (answer1)
print (answer2)
print (answer3)
```

Output:

```
3
5
1
```

If you would like to use `dict`:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[1,0,0]]
answer = {index:str(sum(row)) for index,row in enumerate(matrix)}
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
{0: '3', 1: '5', 2: '1'}
```

Alternatively you can use a `list` to store the answers:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[1,0,0]]
answer = [str(sum(row)) for row in matrix]
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
['3', '5', '1']
```

You can refer to answer 0 with `answer[0]`

Comment: Hi Alex, it is true, but what if each matrix row in my matrix had a different amount of "answers", how can I do the same but with a loop? What if `Matrix = [[1,1,1,5,1],[1,2,2,5,6],[1,0,0,2,5]]`

Comment: I would suggest you to use a dictionary to store the answers.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show how can I use a dictionary to store the answers?

Comment: @JohnFinkelstein done

Answer (score -1):

If you actually want variables answer1 answer2 and answer3 to equal the answers, simply do this

```
for i in answer:
    temp='answer'+str(i+1)+' = str(answer['+str(i)+'])'
    exec(temp)
```

Comment: Please read the question and edit your answer. `exec` is unnecessary for this simple task.

Comment: @AlexFung    I would argue that `exec` is necessary if the amount of numbers in the answer is not specified. The question never specified that it had to be three numbers. It just used three as an example. They also requested that the values be stored as variables. This is why I didn't use a list or dictionary which would be simpler.